# Nested constants of nested structured types are unsupported?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Despite of what Delphi reference says

> structured types can contain other structured types; a type can have unlimited levels of structuring

with notable exception what structured typed constants

> cannot contain file-type values at any level

I discovered what I cannot use record constant as an element of array constant of the same type.

### Testcase

```
type
  MyRecord = record MyField: Integer end;

const
  Typical: array[0..1] of MyRecord = ((MyField: 0), (MyField: 1));

  { now I tried to achieve more clarity by declaring a specific constant }
  Zero: MyRecord = (MyField: 0);

  { and compiler refused to accept that }
  Bad: array[0..1] of MyRecord = (Zero, (MyField: 1));  { E2029 '(' expected but identifier 'Zero' found }
```

I tested this code with several Borland compilers, all of them exhibited the same behaviour. UPD: also the same for FPC, but not for GPC(!).

### Question(s)

What is going on here? Am I correct with "Nested constants of nested structured types are unsupported" conclusion in the question title? Any more analysis of an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this isn't possible, the underlying cause is that ZeroRec isn't truly a constant, it is more like an initialised static variable.

If [{$WRITEABLECONST ON}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Writeable_typed_constants_%28Delphi%29) is specified, then it can be trivially changed. Even with $WRITEABLECONST OFF, it can be changed by some creative type casting (tested in XE2):

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  MyRecord = record MyField: Integer end;
  PMyRecord = ^MyRecord;

const
  Typical: array[0..1] of MyRecord = ((MyField: 0), (MyField: 1));

  { now I tried to achieve more clarity by declaring a specific constant }
  ZeroRec: MyRecord = (MyField: 0);
  { and compiler refused to accept that }
//  Bad: array[0..1] of MyRecord = ((MyField: Zero), (MyField: 1));  { E2029 '(' expected but identifier 'Zero' found }
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    WriteLn(ZeroRec.MyField);
    PMyRecord(@ZeroRec)^.MyField := 2;
    WriteLn(ZeroRec.MyField);
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

This will output

0

2

The behaviour is also evident with simple types,

```
  Zero = 0;
  ZeroRec: MyRecord = (MyField: Zero);
```

compiles as expected, however

```
  Zero : Integer = 0;
  ZeroRec: MyRecord = (MyField: Zero);
```

gives [DCC Error] Project3.dpr(19): E2026 Constant expression expected

Comment: Ah, got it, this is an effect of *constant expression* requirement.

Answer (score 4):

What you are declaring is called a [Typed Constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants). And in this specific case it is an [Array Constant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Array_Constants). The documentation states (emphasis mine):

> To declare an array constant, enclose the values of the array's elements, separated by commas, in parentheses at the end of the declaration. These values must be represented by **constant expressions**.

The code that the compiler objects to is where you attempt to use a typed constant where only a constant expression is allowed.

This is one of the most frustrating areas of the Delphi language because the language forces you to repeat yourself.