# Create array of strings - Const Expression Expected error

Tags: arrays, delphi

I declared two things in my `var` section for this Delphi program:

```
  LCloneTask1, LCloneTask2, LCloneTask3, ... , LCloneTask20 : String;
  CloneTaskArray : array[0..19] of String = (LCloneTask1, LCloneTask2, LCloneTask3,.., LCloneTask20);
```

Where the first line declares some strings and the second line declares an array of said strings. This array is always going to be 20 in size.

When I try to compile I get an error, "Constant expression expected". Am i not declaring a string array properly? I need to be able to read from and write to this array later in the program.

Comment: You don't need the first line at all. Just `CloneTaskArray : array[0..19] of String;`

Comment: If i don't include the first list, I get a bunch of red Undeclared Identifier warnings on the array variable names...

Comment: Use either the array or the variables, not both. You're defining two different places in the memory for two different strings of the same purpose. Rather than reading `LCloneTask1` instead read `CloneTaskArray[0]`. Or, as David describes below, use pointers to those strings.

Comment: Ah, i think i got it. my brain wasn't quite catching up to what you said. 

`CloneTaskArray : array[0..19] of String;`

Comment: See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247819/nested-constants-of-nested-structured-types-are-unsupported).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to initialize a variable as part of its declaration. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables#Declaring_Variables) states that the syntax must be:

> ```
> var identifier: type = constantExpression;
> ```
>
> where constantExpression is any constant expression representing a
>   value of type type.

The [documentation for constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions) says (emphasis mine):

> A constant expression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing the program in which it occurs. Constant expressions include numerals; character strings; true constants; values of enumerated types; the special constants True, False, and nil; and expressions built exclusively from these elements with operators, typecasts, and set constructors. Constant expressions **cannot include variables**, pointers, or function calls.

You are contravening the final sentence, specifically the part that I have highlighted.

---

It's quite possible that all you want to do is declare an array of strings. In which case you would simply write:

```
var
  CloneTaskArray: array[0..19] of string;
```

If you need to initialize this array, do so in the `initialization` section of the unit that declares them:

```
initialization
  CloneTaskArray[0] := 'boo';
  CloneTaskArray[1] := 'yah';
  ....
```

---

I note that you are trying to initialize the elements of the array with other string variables. With a simpler example, I wonder if you are trying to do this:

```
var
  s1, s2: string;
  StringArray: array[0..1] of string;
....
StringArray[0] := s1; 
StringArray[1] := s2;
```

and then I wonder if you are hoping that you can do this:

```
s1 := 'boo';
Assert(StringArray[0] = 'boo');
```

If that's what you are hoping for, you will be disappointed. The string data type in Delphi is quite complex, but fundamentally it behaves like a value type. If you are trying to do what I outline above you'll need to use references to string variables:

```
type
  PString = ^string;
var
  s1, s2: string;
  StringArray: array[0..1] of PString;
....
StringArray[0] := @s1; 
StringArray[1] := @s2;
```

and then you can indeed write:

```
s1 := 'boo';
Assert(StringArray[0]^ = 'boo');
```

Comment: while i think i understand the reasoning on why i/the program cannot initialize a constant expression in the way that i've done it, i still need to try and create the array in the way i described (r/w during the program). is this saying that it cannot be done?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: your comment of using `CloneTaskArray : array[0..19] of string;` as the declaration was sufficient for me to grasp, thanks.

Comment: @ikathegreat it appears that what you want to do is use the pointers, that is, if you really do need to have both the variables *and* the array. Otherwise, choose one or the other.