# How to define a constant record containing other constant records in Delphi? Specific case: matrix using vectors

Tags: delphi, constants, delphi-xe2, record

Say I have a simple record in a unit, such as:

```
TVector2D = record
public
  class function New(const x, y: Accuracy): TVector2D; static;
public
  x, y: Accuracy;
end;
```

I then have a second record in the same unit that is built using a set of the above records, such as:

```
TMatrix3D = record
public
  class function New(const row1, row2, row3: TVector3D): TMatrix3D; static;
public
  Index : array [0..2] of TVector3D;
end;
```

I then define axis direction constants as follows:

```
//Unit vector constants
const
  iHat : TVector3D = (x: 1; y: 0; z: 0);
  jHat : TVector3D = (x: 0; y: 1; z: 0);
  kHat : TVector3D = (x: 0; y: 0; z: 1);
```

I want now to define a further constant using the above constants, something like:

```
  identity : TMatrix3D = (row1: iHat; row2: jHat; row3: kHat);
```

Yet the above attempt doesn't work. How would I do this in Delphi XE2?

Many thanks in advance for your efforts. :-)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247819/nested-constants-of-nested-structured-types-are-unsupported)

Comment: @FreeConsulting - please provide a link

Comment: Ugh, what link?­­­­­­

Comment: A link to the question of which this is a possible duplicate

Comment: I linked that question in the very first comment. No idea why it doesn't work for you. Mobile platform?

Comment: Sorry - my bad. However, although the questions are aiming at similar things, I would argue that they should both remain. I searched for an answer and nothing came up, so I asked a question. Keeping this here stops that from happening again.

Comment: Dunno, in my opinion questions are essentially the same, differing only in phrasing and even both got the answer pointing to constant expression concept ("true constants"). Maybe @RobKennedy some day will take care and make one of QQ more formally phrased and thus search friendly.

Comment: Formal phrasing is not necessarily search friendly...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's not possible. In a constant record declaration, the member values must be [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions). That is, you cannot use typed constants as you have attempted to do.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants) says it like this, with my emphasis:

> **Record Constants**
>
> To declare a record constant, specify the value of each field - as
>   fieldName: value, with the field assignments separated by semicolons -
>   in parentheses at the end of the declaration. The values must be
>   represented by **constant expressions**.

So you need to declare it like this:

```
const
  identity: TMatrix3D = (Index:
    ((x: 1; y: 0; z: 0),
     (x: 0; y: 1; z: 0),
     (x: 0; y: 0; z: 1))
    );
```

Frustrating to have to repeat yourself, but this is the best you can do I suspect.

Comment: @Z80 It's not a keyword it's the name of the field in `TMatrix3D`

Comment: More than 10 versions have come and gone since XE2 but the constant records are still  a blue dream, Even C++ for this time became much more cozy and comfortable to use than Delphi. Don't understand what developers are doing,

Comment: They don't feel presure. That's why i am developing new version of Pascal. Version that is centered on the simplicity and one of the goals is to be better than this old junk. Almost 30 years passed and we still have to hit the wall on every turn. NitroPascal is now a set of proposals to construct new language, that is havely based in Pascal but will be flexible and modern in scripting. Compiler is under development. It is coded in Delphi 10.2+ and it is OpenSource - look at: `https://github.com/gmnevton/NitroPascal/`.